# Embedding lua into c++ but getting unresolved externals : floor, freopen & strcoll

Tags: c++, lua, unresolved-external, premake

I'm embedding lua into a c++ vs2019 solution and it results in linking errors to basic c libraries
( `__imp_freopen`, `__imp_floor` and `__imp_strcoll` ).

lua compiles as a static c library in it's own project and is linked to the main project, but when using `luaL_newstate();` I get unresolved external symbols for `freopen(...)`, `floor(...)` and `strcmp(...)`.

My best guess is that this error comes from my build system (premake5) as when I manually add the project using vs2019 there are no linking errors but since I frequently work on this project across operating systems, not having premake work properly presents many problems.
I'd appreciate any ideas on how to narrow down the problem.

premake for lua :

```
project "lua"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "src/**.c",
        "src/**.h",
        "src/lua.hpp"
    }

    excludes
    {
        "src/lua.c",
        "src/luac.c"
    }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

relevant premake for solution :

```
workspace "solution"
    architecture "x86_64"
    startproject "test"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }
    
    flags
    {
        "MultiProcessorCompile"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

IncludeDir = {}
IncludeDir["GLFW"] = "engine/vendor/GLFW/include"
IncludeDir["Glad"] = "engine/vendor/Glad/include"
IncludeDir["ImGui"] = "engine/vendor/imgui"
IncludeDir["glm"] = "engine/vendor/glm"
IncludeDir["stb_image"] = "engine/vendor/stb_image"
IncludeDir["lua"] = "engine/vendor/lua"

group "dependencies"
    include "engine/vendor/GLFW"
    include "engine/vendor/Glad"
    include "engine/vendor/imgui"
    include "engine/vendor/lua"

group ""

project "engine"
    location "engine"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "on"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    pchheader "pch.h"
    pchsource "engine/src/pch.cpp"

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/stb_image/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/stb_image/**.cpp",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/glm/glm/**.hpp",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/glm/glm/**.inl"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS",
        "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "%{IncludeDir.GLFW}",
        "%{IncludeDir.Glad}",
        "%{IncludeDir.ImGui}",
        "%{IncludeDir.glm}",
        "%{IncludeDir.stb_image}",
        "%{IncludeDir.lua}"
    }

    links
    {
        "GLFW",
        "Glad",
        "ImGui",
        "opengl32.lib",
        "lua"
    }


    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        optimize "off"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
        


project "test"
    location "test"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "on"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp",
        "%{prj.name}/*.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "engine/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "engine/src",
        "engine/vendor",
        "%{IncludeDir.GLFW}",
        "%{IncludeDir.Glad}",
        "%{IncludeDir.ImGui}",
        "%{IncludeDir.glm}"
    }

    links
    {
        "engine"
    }
        
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

lua.hpp is only included in the lua_script.cpp of `class lua_script {...};`

Comment: Probably a mix of runtime libraries between lua and your main project

Comment: It would be less error-prone to build Lua (for Windows) as dynamic library, not static.

Comment: Okay so my temporary solution was to include all lua files directly into the engine project but this isn't ideal as lua really should be it's own project